# What are the differences between the two main brace positions?

Tags: safety, emergency, passenger, emergency-procedures, accident-statistics

- Why are there two different brace positions (pictured below) ?
  *(If there is a difference between the official and true reason, please state both. In many planes the reduced seating spacing does not allow the **pike position** (on the right), but I doubt this is the official statement of airlines.)*
- Are they equally protective ? If not, why are both recommended ?
- What arguments are there in favor or against each ?
- If available, statistical data and relevant links to studies and crash tests would be very welcome if they distinguish between the two positions.

[image: img]

Comment: We have answers on that [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/brace-position-why-hands-atop-head-in-the-uk-but-on-ankles-or-atop-seat-in-fr) and [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11791/in-this-2nd-brace-position-should-your-head-learn-against-the-seat-in-front). Please explain what those two answers leave unclear.

Comment: They don't answer any of the questions above.

Comment: No. [Q12599](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/brace-position-why-hands-atop-head-in-the-uk-but-on-ankles-or-atop-seat-in-fr) is a different question. It is not about the pike position, but about the head-against-seat-in-front-of-you-position and only asks about the arm position in that case. Please remove the comment. Thank you.

Comment: The semi-upright position is the only position available for my portly self.  I can't breathe in the pike position. Perhaps the growing girth in the general population comes into play on the choice of prayer position before the crash.

Answer (score 2):

One is for when the seat in front of you is in the way of using the other.

The other is for when you can't reach a seat in front of you.

They won't both be relevant for the same person in a given seat. If you *can* assume the second position, the first one probably won't provide meaningful support for your head anyway.

Comment: The most useful brace position is when you place your head right down between your legs and kiss your a** goodbye. hardeharhar

Comment: Thanks. This partly answers the question. Remaining questions are: Which of the two is more protective and why? And what reason do airlines give for the existance of 2 positions? I very much doubt they say *"our seats are so close that you cannot use the safer position"* ...

Comment: @summerrain You're assuming that one (specifically the "pike") is automatically "safer" than the other. That isn't necessarily true: in the alternative position, the head is supported by the seat in front -- maybe that's actually beneficial.

Comment: Yes, I assume one is more protective but not which one. I'm just saying IF it's the pike, the official airline statement won't be *"our seats are too close for the safer position"*. But regardless of the merits of either position, I am curious about what reason airlines state for the existance of 2 different positions. I have never heard them say that seat spacing is insufficient. That's not the reason they give. I'll happily stand corrected if provided with such a statement.

Comment: I can't recall an airline ever giving a reason; it's assumed you'll do whichever one matches your body size and available space; there isn't really a choice for any given passenger anyway.

Comment: @summerrain, if you were airborne facing this situation and didn't have your laptop to pose the question, which position would you select - and why?